# Help in decoding this ATC instruction with landing clearance?

Tags: air-traffic-control, phraseology

I was reading the FAA ATC phraseology document (FAA JO Order 7110.65W) and wanted to see if I could get help on decoding what this phrase meant (from the same document):

“American Two Forty−Five, Runway One−Eight, cleared to land, number two following a United Seven−Thirty−Seven two mile final. Traffic will depart prior to your
arrival.”

Does this mean:

`A) American 245 is sequenced to land after the United 737, and the United 737 will vacate the runway before the American lands?`

`B) American 245 is sequenced to land after the United 737. After the United lands, a different aircraft will use the same runway to depart before the American lands?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

B. After the United 737 lands another aircraft will take the runway and depart prior to American 245 landing.

They may not call out what type/make/airline the departing aircraft is. I’ve heard them say ”Company departing prior to your arrival” if the traffic is the same airline though.

> FAA JO Order 7110.65W
>
> 3−10−6. ANTICIPATING SEPARATION
>
> a. Landing clearance to succeeding aircraft in a landing sequence need not be withheld if you observe the positions of the aircraft and determine that prescribed runway separation will exist when the aircraft crosses the landing threshold. Issue traffic information to the succeeding aircraft if a preceding arrival has not been previously reported and **when traffic will be departing prior to their arrival**.

Answer (score 2):

B is correct as AL245 is told by ATC to follow and land #2 after the UAL 737 with a different airplane departing the runway before AL245 arrives.